# How to change SCB->VTOR in app (stm32f4 HAL)?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, bootloader, stm32f4

I build the bootloader for STM32F4 and build user app with the changes the VECT_TAB_OFFSET value manually for SCB->VTOR in system_stm32f4xx.c file but If I do it in the application. It's not working properly.

I called the SCB->VTOR = 0x8040000 at the beginning of the main() but it didn't work.[BOOTLOADER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiTrR.png)
[USER APPLICATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Wsn.png)

Comment: I don't think it should be necessary to set SCB->VTOR in main().  Look for VECT_TAB_OFFSET in system_stm32f4xx.c.  Your SCB->VTOR value may be getting overwritten in the SystemInit() function.

Comment: So how can I call it after SystemInit() function? Where I have to put the SCB->VTOR statement to make the execution works?

Comment: Use the SCB->VTOR assignment that already exists in SystemInit().  Change the value of VECT_TAB_OFFSET to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The STM32 startup code calls `SystemInit()` before `main()`.  `SystemInit()` sets the `SCB->VTOR` value (among other things).  `SystemInit()` is implemented in the vendor provided file `system_stm32f4xx.c`.  You can customize the value that gets assigned to `SCB-VTOR` by editing the value of `VECT_TAB_OFFSET`, which is also defined in `system_stm32f4xx.c`.  (There should be a copy of `system_stm32f4xx.c` in your project folder that you can customize for your project.)

If you need different values of `VECT_TAB_OFFSET` for your boot and application programs then you can use a preprocessor statement like this.  (This allows the boot and application programs to use the same copy of `system_stm32fxx.c`.  Alternatively you could use different copies of the file for each program.)

```
#ifdef BOOT
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET  0x00 /*!< Vector Table base offset field.
                                   This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */
#else
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET  0x80000
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am having a bootloader and two app space which are app1 and app2. Initially working application was in app1 and bootloader boots to app1 when the new update arrives, it stores in app2 then boots to app2 and another update comes it stores in app1 and so on. That's why I have to change the VTOR in run time not at compile time.

Comment: @suriyameras Is your app really relocatable like that?  How are you linking your app such that it is relocatable?  Typically the linker needs to know at build time where the app is going to execute.

Comment: Yeah, I understood. I am asking, "can I build it to work in two memory place?" i.e 0x08020000 & 0x08060000. Because I don't know which place the bootloader will write the new updated app.

Comment: @suriyameras I don't know how to help you with the bootloader design you described.  But maybe you should rethink your bootloader design.  The application gets linked/located to run from a predefined location.  So I think the update needs to be copied to that predefined location before it can be executed.  I typically download the update to a temporary location in flash.  And then after the download is complete and verified correct, the bootloader erases the old application and copies the update application to the executable location.

Comment: ok. Thank you. Like u said I have to redesign my bootloader structure.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this code in main, first line before any other initialization, before HAL_Init or between /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */ /* USER CODE END 1 */

```
__disable_irq();
SCB->VTOR = 0x8008000;
__DSB();
__enable_irq();
```

Don't forgot to preserve bootloader memory window in ld file:

```
FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8008000,   LENGTH = 2048K - 0x8000
```

That's all, even debugger will run this code w/o bootloader in Stm32CubeIDE at offset 0x8008000, but w/o debugger you must have bootloader at start of flash.

Comment: very bad idea to changhe it in main. Bootloader should do it before passing the controll to the app.

Comment: Bad or good, templates from Stm32CubeMX/Stm32CubeIDE don't have user sections to change this without pain. Startup *.s  file have only variables relocation from Flash to RAM code before main() and all works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the VTOR set in the startup file. It should not be there.

Set the `VTOR` in the bootloader before passing the control to the application