# How to change flash start address except linker file

Tags: c, stm32, flash-memory

I need to change my flash jump address when I update firmware. I am using **sm32h750** microcontroller, I can change the application code start address with flash `.ld` (linker) file with this

```
MEMORY
{
    RAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 192K
    CCMRAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
    FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x8100000, LENGTH = 64K
}
```

But I dont want to change anything on this file, I want to change only `FLASH register boot address FLASH_BOOT_CURR)` If I don't change `.ld` file and configure these registers to what I want to start. Is program starts this address or not?

I need this way because of the keep the last code on flash. If I change the flash start address so I can control the where can I copy.
If I change the flash registers at the time of init, will it be enough on its own to start from that address?

Comment: linker script is needed to link properly your app. You cant avoid it. Setting the uC registers do not have anything in common with the linker script,

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different things.

The first one is the microcontroler boot adress. It is specified by the manufacturer. On STM32H7 you can modify this boot adress through a dedicated Flash memory area (obviously this cannot be done through a regular register whose value is lost at power off) called Option bytes. The procedure to modify these option bytes is specific and described in the Reference Manual. The register you are referring to is only reflecting these option bytes but it is read-only. For the record the boot adress on STM32H7 also depends on the value of the BOOT0 pin.

Once you have defined your boot adress, the second point to consider is the linkage of your software. The hardware will jump at the boot address so you obviously have to make sure your binary code is located at this address and formatted as expected.

As a side note, some STM32H7 products (for example STM32H743 and STM32H753) provide a functionality to make firmware update easier, it is called Flash Bank Swapping, it avoids the need to modify the boot adress or firmware linkage. If firmware update is a big concern on your product, you might consider switching to STM32H753.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a simple #define for that specific address in which you want to save the new firmware? I think you can do it in the main file.
Also check this answer from another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64253004/10738372

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).